# How I can I add audio to my ffmpeg cli

Tags: ffmpeg, livestreamer

I want to add audio to my ffmpeg cli bellow

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -video_size 1920x1080 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -vf format=yuv420p http://localhost:8080/feed.ffm
```

Comment: Don't have time for an answer today, maybe this will suffice for background audio..You can add after -i :0.0 this, `-f alsa -i pulse`  plus also audio codec to be used, ex. `-c:a aac`  or whatever. Then in at least Ubuntu a one time setup. Install `pavucontrol`, open it, click on the Recording tab. Start your ffmpeg command, you'll see `Alsa plugin [ffmpeg]` appear. Switch it to `Monitor of Built-in Audio ..`  after this it'll always use the Monitor for the Alsa plugin.  (Don't have a mic so never tried that audio input..

Comment: there is no Alsa plugin in `pavucontrol` after I start my [ffmpeg] cli

Comment: Sorry, I glossed over your using a local server. What I described was how to input system audio into a ffmpeg recording/encoding. No clue what you'd do with ffserver now gone.

Comment: https://www.how2shout.com/linux/install-openshot-video-editor-on-ubuntu-20-04/